# How to use a variable of second constructor function in Node.js? (using import/export)

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, constructor, export

I have 3 different `.js` files that are linked between them by `import/export` keywords. Each of the files have their own specific functions like this:

---

1. `Init.js`: Invokes `Event.js` and `Touch.js`. Send the variables to
   `Event.js`.
2. `Event.js`: Receives the variables from `Init.js` and registers the
   `event` to each of the elements.
3. `Touch.js`: Recognizes the `event` id from `Event.js` then logs it.

---

A problem is the constructor function of `Touch.js` doesn't work at all. The browser can't access to it. It keeps firing `undefined` when I try to log it the local variables called `A` and `B`.

The only possible way that I've found is to create the variables from `Init.js`, pass them to `Event.js`, and pass again to `Touch.js` like I've done below.

Are there any ways to use the local variables of its own constructor function?

See the code below:

```
//============== Init.js ==============
'use strict';
import {Event} from './event.js';
import { proTouch } from './touch.js';
const slider = (function() {
    class Slider {
        constructor(elem) {
            this.elem = document.querySelectorAll(elem);
            this.C = false;
            this.Event = new Event();
            this.Event.register(this.elem, 'mouseenter', proTouch.start, this.C);
        }
    }
    return {
        initialize: new Slider('.box')
    }
}());

//============== Event.js ==============

export class Event {
    constructor() {

    }
    register(node, eventName, callback, flag) {
        let bind = callback.bind(this);
        node.forEach(cur => {
            cur.addEventListener(eventName, (e) => bind(e, flag))
        })
    }
}


//============== Touch.js ==============

class Touch {
    constructor() {
        this.A = false;
        this.B = true; // <-- I want to use this constructor function.
    }
    start(e, flag) {
        console.log(e.type, this.A, this.B, flag); // <-- this.A and this.B fire undefined.
    }
}
const proTouch = new Touch();
export { proTouch }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Event` class, you are binding the callback to `this`. That is wrong because in this context `this` is `Event` instance and doesn't contain `a` or `b` variable. Delete that line.

```
let bind = callback.bind(this);//Wrong. Delete this line.
```

When you are Sending the callback you want to bind the `proTouch` to the `start` method. So, bind there.

```
this.Event.register(this.elem, 'mouseenter', proTouch.start.bind(proTouch), this.C);
```

Comment: My Freaking God you saved my life! Thank you so much.